# How to set a <div> tag text value from Google Apps Script with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dom, web-applications

How are the elements `foo` and `bar` set to the values for their corresponding variables?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    function sendFoo()
    {
      var foo = document.getElementById("foo").value;
      google.script.run.setFoo(foo);
      var bar = google.script.run.getBar();
      document.getElementById("foo").value = '';
      document.getElementById("bar").childNodes[0].textContent = "put variable here..";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  foo is:<input type="text" id="foo" />
  <input type="button" value="sendFoo" onclick="sendFoo()" /> <br> <br> <br>


    bar is:  <div id="bar">Change only me<div>but not me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

code:

```
const SPREADSHEET_ID = "1L3Sd-J780mQtb7JYsmJzInI1kMdrQA8GbLspQJ5eVW4";
const SPREADSHEET_NAME = "data";

function setFoo(foo) {
  // Logger.log("setFoo..");
  // Logger.log(foo);
}

function getBar() {
  //  Logger.log("getBar..");
  return "baz";
}


function getUrl() {
  // Logger.log("getUrl..");

  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}


function doGet(e) {
  // Logger.log("doGet..");
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('FooBarBaz');
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

Server side logs show `foo` and `bar` values when uncommented.  However, there seems no output from `console.log("some text");` from within the function defined on the `HTML` page.

Comment: In the `script` of `html` file, you have just assigned the constant values to the elements. What value you are expecting?

Comment: Assigning a var gives no output in GAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the response of the google script function, then you will have to call that with [success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction).
`google.script.run.getBar()` should be updated as:

```js
var bar = '';
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((response)=>{
  bar = response;
  console.log(response); // prints 'baz' on console.
}).getBar();
```

You can use this value to assign to the div or perform some other operations.

Comment: I'm not getting console logs in `Google Apps Script` executions, as you have above, and as I would expect.  Although I do have `Logger.log()` output, but that's only on the server side.  Some logging from the client side would be useful.  (Although, if the log from the "client" side shows in the server logs, not sure how that's from the "client" side.)  I'll try and trace the error, but this looks like the solution.  Possibly I have typo, or something along those lines, which needs to be fixed for your solution to work.  Your explanation is quite helpful.

Comment: `console.log` will print at the user's console and it is printing (I have tested it).
The code in the `.gs` file will create logs on the server (not the client side `js`)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendFoo()
    {
      var foo = document.getElementById("foo").value;
      google.script.run.setFoo(foo);
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((s) => {
        document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = s;
      })
      .getBar();
      document.getElementById("foo").value = '';
      document.getElementById("bar").childNodes[0].textContent = "put variable here..";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just including this as a more full answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
    var foo = "";
    var bar = "";
    function sendFoo()
    {
      consoleLogger();
      foo = document.getElementById("foo").value;
      google.script.run.setFoo(foo);
      document.getElementById("fooVal").textContent = foo;
      foo = "";
      document.getElementById("foo").value = foo;

      bar = google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler((success) => {
        document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = success;
      })
      .getBar();
      document.getElementById("bar").textContent = bar;
      consoleLogger();
    }

    function consoleLogger()
    {
      console.log(foo);
      console.log(bar);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  foo is:<input type="text" id="foo" />
  <input type="button" value="sendFoo" onclick="sendFoo()" /> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    foo entered: <div id="fooVal"></div>
    bar is:      <div id="bar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

does a bit more logging, shows the `foo` entered, and `bar` value from server side.

Ideally, would switch to the `#` query selector notation rather than using `id`.